# DebugView android studio kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

prompt, I use android studio kotlin

statistics are entered into Firebase Analytics when I run the application through the Android Studio emulator, but for some reason it is not entered when I use a real device that I connect via USB with debugging

in the terminal Command - adb devices shows 2 devices
emulator and real device

I tried different phones, it still didn’t help, if it’s the logic itself, which way to dig?